# Friend selector plugin (no FBML ?)

Tags: facebook, multi-friend-selector

Since this message on the fb:friend-selector page :

> FBML has been deprecated. Starting June 1, 2012 FBML apps will no
>   longer work as all FBML endpoints will be removed. If you are building
>   a new application on Facebook.com, please implement your application
>   using HTML, JavaScript and CSS. You can use our JavaScript SDK and
>   Social Plugins to embedded many of the same social features available
>   in FBML.

So in order to use the fb friend selector to send requests to some friends, i must use my own application and use SDK to do this ?

There is no "widget" to do this ?

Thanks you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need a facebook application to send requests.

For sending requests, facebook provide a new dialog, called "[requests dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)", you can use the Javascript SDK's `FB.ui` function to access it.

You might need to redo (or implement) request handling in your application because the new [requests 2.0 API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/) make the developer's responsibility to [delete requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/#deleting).

Comment: OK thanks you for the answer. So the user must accept my application in order to watch the friend selector generated by FB.ui function.